# Which versions of Cassandra is compatible with Astyanax 3.10.x

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

I'm looking at https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Cassandra-compatibility and it doesn't seem to be updated to current versions. 
I'm currently using Cassandra 2.0.x and I am wondering if it's compatible with Astyanax 3.10.x, since it's causing a few tests to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding Cassandra 2.0 was the last one added, it seems like astyanax is retired. Its possible that some releases on 2.0.X would work but the errors you are seeing are probably due to the new changes/functionality added to Cassandra which is not supported by astyanax.

[Here](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki) is their last update where they suggest switching to [datastax](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver)

If you really need to use astyanax i would suggest going down to Cassandra 2.0 otherwise it might be best to switch to datastax